# Overleaf doesn't create files specified by the filecontents environment

Tags: overleaf, filecontents

A new Overleaf project titled `Test` was created. Upon creation it contained a single file called `main.tex`. The default contents of this file were replaced by the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Test.txt}
A test file.
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

The Overleaf settings were configured as follows.

> Compiler ... LuaLaTex
> TeX Live version ... 2022
> Main document ... main.tex

The project was then compiled. It compiled successfully and produced in the PDF view a single, numbered page containing the phrase "Hello, world!", and nothing else.

I'd expected a file by the name of `Test.txt` to be created in the working directory, but there was no indication of such a file. The only file listed in the files panel was `main.tex`, as before.

Why wasn't a file named `Test.txt` listed in the files panel in addition to `main.tex`? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: In Overleaf, dynamically created files are kept in the cache, which you can access - they are not added to the source list shown in the file tree. If you amend your example and put `\input{Test.txt}`, you'll see that you can input the generated file. You can also download the generated file (and others) from the cache from the "logs and output files" pane. Feel free to reach out to Overleaf support if you want more info on Overleaf behaviour that you can't find in the documentation.

Comment: @DanMacKinnon Oh, I see. Thanks.